# Using pybind11 to wrap an stl container (map) that includes Eigen arrays

Tags: python, c++, eigen, pybind11

I know how to pass Eigen arrays from c++ to Python. However, in my c++ code, I have an `stl::map` of Eigen arrays. For example, it would look like this

```
std::map <string, Eigen::ArrayXd>  myMap;
```

and I would have add elements to this map by doing:

```
myMap['key1'] = Eigen::MatrixXd::Constant(100, 1, 0.0).array()
myMap['key2'] = Eigen::MatrixXd::Constant(100, 1, 0.0).array()
```

Is it possible to return in Python a dictionary where keys are strings and values are numpy arrays? I'm not sure if this is possible through pybind11 and I'm totally stuck.

Comment: (I don't have an answer, nor really an idea if yes/no you would need to extend pybind11's capabilities.) An obvious question is: are you able to get things working for something simpler? For example an `std::map<std::string, int>`.